# Load one image for mobile site and hide another, load the hidden image and hide the mobile image on Squarespace

Tags: html, css, squarespace

On my squarespace website (http://rmcclainmedia.com) I have an image on the second of the index page. Right now it is "Client-logos.png". That image is not easy to see on a mobile platform. Therefore, I'd like to build some sort of code that when someone accesses from a desktop program, the image I want to display is visible and the display for the mobile image is hidden. And for mobile, I want it to be vice versa. I understand the process that needs to happen, just don't know the right way to write this code and inject it into my squarespace page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, generally we encourage users to try and post questions which are able to be verified and answered, as this sort of question could lead to several opinion-based answers. 

That being said, I would check out the [picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options for approaches to handle this in Squarespace from a general perspective:

1. Use CSS media queries to simply hide/show the specific section or block based on browser width.
2. Use CSS media queries to hide/show the section or block and correspondingly show/hide a different section or block in its place based on browser width.
3. Use a different type of block, such as a gallery or summary block, rather than an image block, which will adjust its own layout based on browser width.

Note that the `section` IDs used in the following examples assume that your first [index section URL slug](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/207842357-Adding-Index-Page-anchor-links) is "new-page" and the second is named "new-page-mobile". Squarespace will generate IDs from the URL slug. This is an example; yours may vary. CSS should be added via [the CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor). Also note that, if showing/hiding *blocks* instead of *sections*, the code below would need to change to use block IDs instead of section IDs.

Option 1 is simple enough. In your specific case, the following CSS inserted via the CSS Editor will accomplish it:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  #new-page {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Option 2 is similar of course, except that instead of simply hiding the section, you would also show another. This assumes you've created an additional index page section right below the first one in question:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640.1px) {
  #new-page {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:640px) {
  #new-page-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

As to option 3, by using a [gallery block grid](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544027-Using-Grid-Gallery-Blocks) or [summary block grid](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813768-Using-Grid-Summary-Blocks) layout, and uploading the logos individually, the layout will manage itself to some degree, stacking the logos at narrower widths.

(Aside: I initially thought you were talking about the image on the "about" page, which isn't ideally composed on mobile devices because you, the subject, are off-screen. If you end up wanting a solution to that, post a new question.)